# Send dialog response vs Feed dialog response

Tags: facebook, dialog, response, send, facebook-messages

I tried both "send" and "feed" dialogs directly with urls as [described in documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/).

**Feed dialog:**
Everything works fine; my redirect_uri is:

- called as is when the "cancel" button is clicked (`http://my.redirect.uri`)
- called with the query string "post_id=123456789" when the "share" button is clicked (`http://my.redirect.uri?post_id=123456789`)

Then I'm able to check the posted link thanks to the received id (if I have the "read_stream" permission of course).

**Send dialog:**
The response is not the same; my redirect_uri is:

- called as is when the "cancel" button is clicked (`http://my.redirect.uri`)
- called with the query string "success=1" when the "share" button is clicked (`http://my.redirect.uri?success=1`)

I would like to read the sent Message or the related Thread (with the "read_mailbox" permission), but I don't know the message id. I'm able to look for this message in the whole inbox, but this is not really satisfaying to me...

**My questions:**

- Is there a way to get this id when coming back from Facebook Send Dialog?
- Why isn't this id given in the redirect_uri query string like it is done with the feed dialog? (something like `http://my.redirect.uri?message_id=123456789`)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get this id when coming back from Facebook Send Dialog?

No. The Send dialog only reports success, but nothing else.

> Why isn't this id given in the redirect_uri query string like it is done with the feed dialog?

Because the Send dialog does not give that info at all, no matter how you call it. Using the JS SDK f.e., calling it with FB.ui, you also only get a true/false return value.

My guess is that this is by design; FB does not want you to know who the user sends messages to or what they contain.

Comment: *FB does not want you to know who the user sends messages to or what they contain*.  
But if I really want to know who the user sent the message I prepared for him, I am able to read the whole user inbox (with the "read_mailbox" permission) and look for this message.  
IMHO, it just would be useful to have the message id (like we have the post id with the feed dialog).  
If I want more information about the sent message, I would anyway have to ask for "read_mailbox" permission (like I have to ask for "read_stream" permission when I want more information about a post shared from feed dialog)